# Something is wrong

Tags: floats, positioning

Why is my figure 1 above the "Results" section? What is wrong with my code? It fine was fine until I added

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Figuren är inritad i ett koordinatsystem mätt i SI-enheten centimeter.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[ht]` for example.

Comment: Please add a MWE instead of a screenshot of the code, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: This is a natural behavior of a float environment, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat.

Comment: @hair-splitter thank you!